# Add a Reference to 3rd party DLL in Visual studio 2010- Sandbox Solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, dll, sharepoint-2010

I need to add the Repatcha.dll as a reference to my sharepoint sandbox solution. How can I refer to this DLL using Visual studio 2010?

It should be packaged and needed to upload to the online site as a sandbox solution.Please provide me the steps to add the reference to my project.

Please help.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: ReCaptcha is available on NuGet.  It would be incredibly easy to have it installed in your project via the package manager console --  `Install-Package RecaptchaNet`

Comment: @George: thanks. but im using vs2010 for development.nuget is not available in it.hw can i achieve this in 2010?

Answer (score 3):

You cand add the assemblie reference to VS like others projects using Add Reference or Nuget.

The second step is use the package configuration in order to deploy the reqeuired assembly to the target machine.

Check the "Advanced" package configuration from your webpart solution. There is some configuration relative to others assemblies that you can register into GAC or WebApplication.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. Im using vs 2010 for development.may i knw the way achieve this in 2010?

Comment: In VS 2010 you can do this by the same way.

Comment: Yes True. I am stuck with adding this assembly in Web application or GAC since I am developing a Sanbox solution. If i add it in Gacc it didnt work. And Web application in a Sandbox solutions don't have rights. How can i achive it in sandbox?

Comment: There is not restriction to add assemblies in a sandboxed solution http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee231595(v=vs.100).aspx